# Null-coalescing operator and operator && in C#

Tags: c#, boolean-logic, logical-operators, null-coalescing-operator

Is it possible to use together any way operator `??` and operator `&&` in next case:

```
bool? Any
{
   get
   {
      var any = this.ViewState["any"] as bool?;
      return any.HasValue ? any.Value && this.SomeBool : any;
   }
}
```

This means next:

- if `any` is null then `this.Any.HasValue` return `false`
- if `any` has value, then it returns value considering another boolean property, i.e. `Any && SomeBool`

Comment: Why would you want to use the ?? operator? To make it shorter?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Yes. And for operators usage practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering why nobody has suggested this so far:

```
bool? any = this.ViewState["any"] as bool?;
return any & this.SomeBool;
```

This returns

- `null` if `any` is null, no matter what the value of `this.SomeBool` is;
- `true` if both `any` and `this.SomeBool` are true; and
- `false` if `any` is not null, and `this.SomeBool` is false.

Comment: code looks good, description is wrong though (how can you return both `null` and `false` at the same time, yet that's what your rules say would happen for `any == null` and `this.SomeBool == false`.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Why are the operands `'bool' and 'bool?'` and not `'bool?' and 'bool'`!? The left operand is clearly of type `bool?` as I declared it as such.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Yes, but I made a typo when copying it to my answer :-( Fixed it now. My test program: `bool? x = null; bool y = true; bool? z = x & y;`

Comment: Your code can be rewritten as: `return this.ViewState["any"] as bool? & this.SomeBool;`, right?

Comment: @abatishchev: I think so. May need some `(`/`)`.

Comment: An important caveat: `&&` is a short-circuiting boolean evaluation, but the bitwise evaluator `&` **doesn't** short-circuit. Therefore, in the above, this.SomeBool will be evaluated regardless. So be mindful that this is not a complete replacement for the typical usage of `&&` when using `Nullable<bool>`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to return `null` in case the source is `null`, I don't think `??` is going to help you write this any shorter or clearer.

Comment: It seems that you're right. Operator `??` is for returning a value in any case. This is exactly what I don't need..

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
bool? Any 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return ((this.ViewState["any"] as bool?) ?? false) && this.SomeBool;
   } 
}
```

I've left the return value as bool? but it looks like it could be changed to just bool.

This was tested like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> ViewState = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private static bool SomeBool;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)null; SomeBool = true; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)false; SomeBool = true; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)true; SomeBool = true; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)null; SomeBool = false; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)false; SomeBool = false; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        ViewState["any"] = (bool?)true; SomeBool = false; Console.WriteLine(Any);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool? Any
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ViewState["any"] as bool?) ?? false) && SomeBool;
        }
    }
}
```

which returns

```
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

The behaviour here is not quite the same as the original as null should be returned for test cases 1 and 4 to be identical.  But maybe that behaviour isn't required?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `result as bool?` has always `HasValue = true`. doesn't it?

Comment: He wants to return null if any is null AND the two other conditions are false.  So, he wants TRUE, FALSE and NULL

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much for your detailed answer! But unfortunately we talk about different behaviors - I need to keep return value being `Nullable<bool>` so checking to `HasValue` would have a sense

Comment: I understand and in that case I agree with Henk that there isn't any way to use ?? and && in a way that makes it shorter/clearer whilst maintaining that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The Null Coalescing operator isn't going to work for how you've structured the logic for your method. Sure you could force it in there, but it's going to look ugly and just confuse whomever reads it.

I found the original code hard to read and understand, so refactored and removed the ternary operator to reveal intentions.

```
bool? any = this.ViewState["any"] as bool?;

if (any == null)
    return null;

return any.Value && this.SomeBool;
```

---

Null coalescing is just nice shorthand and should be used judiciously

```
Person contact = Mother ?? Father ?? FirstSibling;
```

Is more intention revealing, and easier to read + maintain than:

```
Person contact = Mother;
if (contact == null)
    contact = Father;
if (contact == null)
    contact = FirstSibling;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
return any ?? (any.Value && this.SomeBool) ? true : new Nullable<bool>();
```

However, I think in cases like this, it's probably more clear to use an if block:

```
if ( !any.HasValue )
  return (any.Value && this.SomeBool) ? true : any;
else 
  return any;
```

If any is `null`, then you want to return `true` or `null`, right?

Answer (score 1):

thing is, you don't really want to use the ?? operator.   Its meant to make it easy to avoid nulls, you actually want to keep nulls.

Answer (score -1):

This has the behavior you describe:

`return (any ?? false) && this.SomeBool`

Comment: As Daniel Renshaw's answer, yours one also always has value - `true` or `false`, never `null`